# How to get value of field from wizard to qweb odoo?

Tags: odoo, qweb

I have defined a model to display a wizard which holds one many2one field and one selection field. This wizard will be displayed in inventory while clicking a custom defined menu comes under reporting menu. I created a button in wizard to print qweb.

What i need to do is, to fetch the value of that selection field in qweb.

Could anyone please help me to fetch value of fields from wizard in qweb odoo14?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please tell the model of qweb? Also are you gonna print the report from wizard only?

Comment: No, actually everything works fine in my report except fetching a single field's value from wizard to print it in qweb.

Comment: Try printing the report using with_context element in your calling function.EX: return self.env.ref('ref').with_context(discard_logo_check=True).report_action(list)

Comment: Thanks @ himanshu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use "context"

Here is an explanation:
https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/what-s-the-context-2236